# Enable brower shortcuts in a browser pdf

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, shortcuts, pdf-reader

So I have recently tried to start learning shortcuts for certain commands and I have gotten pretty proficient and reliant on the shortcuts that I do know. Now, when I am unable to use my shortcuts, it actually becomes a big hindrance to me (more mentally then time-wise I guess). I have long noticed that when I open a pdf in a browser it eats up all of the keyboard shortcuts. Is there a way that I can block this? For one I don't see much benefit to it since I don't use any pdf shortcuts really, but I can't switch through tabs like I normally do which is what really bugs me.

My question: Is there a way to view a pdf in a browser that still leaves the browser shortcuts intact?

Comment: I am using firefox and windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that Firefox is the browser that you are using.

In Firefox, when a plugin has focus, it intercepts all keyboard shortcuts. As far as I know, this is by design, though there have been some incomplete attempts to at let stop all of the keyboard shortcuts from being intercepted:

> https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Plugin_keyboard_focus#Stage_1:_Definition 
>   https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181177#c1

Internet Explorer and Google Chrome also seem to send all keyboard shortcuts to plugins when they have focus.

As a potential solution, the built-in pdf viewer in Google Chrome does not block the browser's keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I will try out google chrome...If it works how you say, I might need to switch browsers

Comment: Wow, that is pretty nice. I tried google chrome and it worked. Still looking for a work around in firefox if available